# I need help in modifying a food ordering system. Using a list to take order item key with quantity. This is for Python

Tags: python, list, loops, append, nested-lists

This code below has been given to produce an output that will show an ordering system. I need help to create a list to take order item key with quantity.
So a sample List format for order taken:
[[1,2], [3,1]] meaning item Big Mac (id 1) has quantity 2 and item Vegetarian Burger (id 3) has quantity 1 ordered.
Basically I will need to create an empty list before a loop starts, then add a nested list each time an order entered with id and quantity by appending your list. But I don't know how and where to begin. Can anyone help?

```
def processOrder(quantity, item_list):
    global total
    if quantity > item_list[2]:
        print("There is not enough stock!")
        pass
    else:
        total += item_list[1] * quantity
        item_list[2] -= quantity

total = 0
A = ["Big Mac", float(2.50), 50], ["Large Fries", float(0.50), 200], ["Vegetarian Burger", float(1.00), 20]

print("Welcome to McDonald's")
print("[1]", A[0][0:2],
      "\n[2]", A[1][0:2],
      "\n[3]", A[2][0:2])

more_items = 'yes'
while more_items == 'yes':
    choice, quantity = int((input("\nWhat would you like?\n"))), int(input("\nHow many would you like?\n"))
    if 1 <= choice <= 3:
        processOrder(quantity, A[choice-1])

more_items = (input("Do you want to order more items?")).lower()
print("Thank you for ordering!\nYour total cost is: $" +  str(total))
```

I tried creating a new function to get order item key with quantity like this:

```
# Function to get order item key with quantity
def get_order_item_with_quantity(items, quantity):
    empty_list = []
    
    for items in A:
        empty_list.append([A])
```

But I'm really stuck on where to go from here or whether this is the right way to do it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be necessary to write a function in this case, a simple `append()` would suffice. I've added a few lines to your code - see `#added` comments

```
def processOrder(quantity, item_list):
    global total
    if quantity > item_list[2]:
        print("There is not enough stock!")
        pass
    else:
        total += item_list[1] * quantity
        item_list[2] -= quantity


total = 0
A = ["Big Mac", float(2.50), 50], ["Large Fries", float(0.50), 200], ["Vegetarian Burger", float(1.00), 20]

print("Welcome to McDonald's")
print("[1]", A[0][0:2],
      "\n[2]", A[1][0:2],
      "\n[3]", A[2][0:2])

order = [] # added - initail empty order
more_items = 'yes'
while more_items == 'yes':
    choice, quantity = int((input("\nWhat would you like?\n"))), int(input("\nHow many would you like?\n"))
    if 1 <= choice <= 3:
        processOrder(quantity, A[choice - 1])
        order.append([choice-1, quantity]) # added - append the order with the current position
    more_items = (input("Do you want to order more items?")).lower()
print("Thank you for ordering!\nYour total cost is: $" + str(total))
#added - print out the order list
print('Order list:')
for el in order:
    print(f'Position: {A[el[0]][0]}, quantity: {el[1]}, cost: {A[el[0]][1]*el[1]}')
```

```
Welcome to McDonald's
[1] ['Big Mac', 2.5] 
[2] ['Large Fries', 0.5] 
[3] ['Vegetarian Burger', 1.0]

What would you like?
1

How many would you like?
2
Do you want to order more items?yes

What would you like?
3

How many would you like?
1
Do you want to order more items?
Thank you for ordering!
Your total cost is: $6.0
Order list:
Position: Big Mac, quantity: 2, cost: 5.0
Position: Vegetarian Burger, quantity: 1, cost: 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think it would be that simple. Appreciate it!